# Enabling Release Management in Bamboo

Tags: release, jira, bamboo

I'm running JIRA and Bamboo which are connected by the application link. In Bamboo, there is a Maven project with the following POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.experiments</groupId>
<artifactId>howto-release</artifactId>
<version>${ci.version}</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>howto-release</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <ci.version>2.6-SNAPSHOT</ci.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.xxx.lan/svn/howto-release/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn.xxx.lan/svn/howto-release/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>http://svn.xxx.lan/svn/howto-release/trunk</url>
</scm>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta-8</version>
            <configuration>
                <tagBase>http://svn.xxx.lan/svn/howto-release/tag</tagBase>
                <username>release-user</username>
                <password>release-user</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The maven goal definition in Bamboo looks like this:

```
clean install -Dci.version=${bamboo.custom.brmp.name}
```

By now, I want to use the incorporated feature "release management" as described here:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OH-Iq4z8Mj8
- http://blogs.atlassian.com/2010/09/bamboo_jira_release_management_plugin_part_2/

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as described by the Atlassian guys. There is no "enable release management" checkbox in "Plan configuration / Miscellaneous".

I have also troubles with the Release button in JIRA which currently issues an error message like this: "Bamboo server has not returned any Plans."

Does anybody know how to deal with the automated release management plugin in Bamboo and what I have to do to get the options visible (see "Plan configuration / Miscellaneous")?

I'm running the following versions of JIRA and Bamboo:

- JIRA version v5.1.5#784-sha1:6c72993
- Bamboo Version 4.4.0 build 3501 - 28 Jan 13.

Your help is appreciated!!
Thank you.

Katarina